# Is there any trick to make a Blog Site available in more than 1 language

Tags: blog, multilingual

I tried to add a language on a Blog Site Template and the following error occurs:

> This site is based on a site template that does not support alternate
>   languages

Now is there any chance to make this blog site appear on two languages.

I installed language packs for the other language.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there's no option you are looking for. Only Team Sites can be switched to a multilingual UI.